# Change link after submitted the form (ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

I have one question. How to change the link after the user has submitted the form? What I mean is that once the user submit the form, the link that direct the user to the FORM will be change to another url which is ViewFormA.asp. How can I do that? Need your advice. Thanks.

Comment: After the user has submitted the form, the page goes away, so there's no link to change.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to allow exactly 1 user access to the form exactly 1 time?  OR do you mean that any user can access the form exactly 1 time?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

`Response.Redirect "/ViewFormA.asp"`

Comment: Thanks..

but what if I want to change the link url permanently..the user still can access the FORM page even though they have submitted the form..any idea?

Comment: I don't want the user to access the form anymore once they have submitted the form..

Comment: So you want to deny user from ever seeing the form again if they've already submmited it, don't matter what they do?

Answer (score 0):

at first, in the beginning of FORM page on the server side you need to check your own special Cookie or Session variable (like Session("AlreadySubmitted"))
a) if this variable is exist , it means that the user already submitted the form and must be redirected to an other page.
b) if this variable is not exist yet or equal to zero , the user is allowed to fill the FORM and submit the data.

at second, on a page that get submitted data you have to set this variable to 1